# how to check if the contents of one file are included in another file in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to check if the contents of one file are included in another file in ruby..

```
uploaded_doc = File.readlines("scrapped.txt")
scrapped_doc = File.readlines("makefile.txt")

uploaded_doc.each do |upload_lines|
  if scrapped_doc.include?(upload_lines)
    puts "common lines: "
    puts upload_lines
  else
    puts "no common lines detected "
  end
end
```

The two files `makefile.txt` and `scrapped.txt`  have the same content...but the code in the `else` is the one that is always executed...Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is `scrap`? What is `upload`? When you iterate over an array, you get a single element in each loop. `upload_lines` should probably be `upload_line`. Why is `scrapped_doc` not from `scrapped.txt`?

Comment: Sorry about that...They are `scrapped_doc` and ` uploaded_doc`  respectively ...

Comment: You need to edit your question to make the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement and the algorithm you are trying to implement are not matching.

Your algorithm is simply checking if elements of one array(uploaded_doc) are also present in scrapped_doc. If this is what you really want, simply do:

```
(uploaded_doc - scrapped_doc).none?
```

It will be true if all the elements of uploaded_doc are in scrapped_doc.

Now, back to your requirement, do you want to ensure that both of the files have exactly same number of lines? If so, in addition to the above you should also check sizes.

```
(uploaded_doc - scrapped_doc).none? && uploaded_doc.size == scrapped_doc.size
```

hmmmm, that is better but still has one more issue. Can you figure it out?
hint:

```
2.2.0 :001 > A = [1,2,2]  => [1, 2, 2] 
2.2.0 :002 > B = [2,1,1]  => [2, 1, 1] 
2.2.0 :003 > (A - B).none? && A.size == B.size  
=> true
```

Comment: thanks...though the app i'm building is a plagiarism app...checks for instances of copied lines by comparing an uploaded document and scrapped data from web pages stored in a file...